# Switching the bounds on the integral in the first step of proving that $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{1}{n}=\log(x)+\gamma+O(1/x).$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show $$\sum_{n\le x} \frac{1}{n}=\log(x)+\gamma+O(1/x),$$ where $$\gamma=1-\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t-\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^2}dt.$$

The only step in the proof that I don't quite understand is this one,
$$\sum_{n\le x} \frac{1}{n}=\sum_{n\le x}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\int_{n}^{x} \frac{dt}{t^2}\right)= \frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{x}+\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^2}dt.$$ I understand how to get the integral in the first equality. But I don't understand the change of bounds in the second integral. My professor explained it as multiplying the integrand by a function $f(n,t)$ where $f(n,t)=1$ when $n\le t$ and $f(n,t)=0$ when $n>t$. So you get
$$\sum_{n\le x}\int_{n}^{x}\frac{dt}{t^2}=\sum_{n\le x}\int_{1}^{x}f(n,t)\frac{dt}{t^2}=\int_{n}^{x}\sum_{n\le x}f(n,t)\frac{dt}{t^2}=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^2}dt.$$
This has me completely confused.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Note that the [number-theory] and [elementary-number-theory] tags are pretty much mutually exclusionary: a given question should qualify for one but the other, as explained in their descriptions. Also, I am not sure this is even number theory....

Comment: It was done in a number theory course for the arithmetical functions section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the last sum as:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\le x}\int_{n}^{x}\frac{dt}{t^2} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\int_{n}^{x}\frac{dt}{t^2}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\left(\sum_{k=n}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dt}{t^2}+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^{x}\frac{dt}{t^2}\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\sum_{k=n}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dt}{t^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^{x}\frac{dt}{t^2}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}\sum_{n=1}^{k}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dt}{t^2}+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^{x}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{t^2}dt\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{k}{t^2}dt+\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^{x}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{t^2}dt
\end{align*}

You can then see that $k=\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor t\rfloor$ in each interval you're integrating on!

$$=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\lfloor t\rfloor}{t^2}dt$$

And voilá. Hope it helps!

(Sorry I misread the question).

Comment: Can someone help me indent this properly? Thanks!

Comment: I get why $k=\lfloor x\rfloor$ but could you explain why $\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor t\rfloor$?

Comment: By definition of the floor function, $x\in [\lfloor x\rfloor; \lfloor x\rfloor +1[$ and so also $t$ is in that interval, meaning $\lfloor x\rfloor=\lfloor t\rfloor$.